# How do I get a serialized object to look the same as it's original source xml file?

Tags: c#, xml, serialization, xsd

I have a xsd file, defined by an external company, that I used with xsd.exe to generate classes. I can use a provided xml file to deserialize into an object using the generated classes just fine, but there are a few cases where I need to have smaller portions of the xml as a XDocument. I won't know the path in these portions until run time, so I'm using the xml for:

```
XElement element = xml.XPathSelectElement(path);
```

The issue I'm having is that serialized result doesn't match the incoming xml quite right, which makes the select return null. How do I get a serialized object to look like the incoming file? Did I possibly generate the classes incorrectly with xsd.exe? I'll eventually need to use the same generated code to generate my own xml files.

Here's the code I'm currently using to serialize

```
var xml = new XDocument();
using (var writer = xml.CreateWriter())
{
    List<Type> known = new List<Type>();
    known.Add(typeof(ObjType1));
    ...
    var serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Detail), known);
    serializer.WriteObject(writer, sourceDetailObj);
}
```

The serialized result:

```
<Detail xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/CustomNameSpace">
    ...
    <numberField>1</numberField>
    <detailTypeField>
        <objField i:type="ObjType1">
            <valObjField i:nil="true" />
            ...
        </objField>
    </detailTypeField>
    ...
</Detail>
```

What it should look like:

```
<Detail>
    ...
    <Number>1</Number>
    <DetailType>
        <ObjType1>
            ...
        </ObjType1>
    </DetailType>
    ...
</Detail>
```

Here's one of the classes xsd generates:

```
public partial class DetailType {

    private object objField;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("ObjType1", typeof(ObjType1))]
    ...
    public object Obj {
        get {
            return this.objField;
        }
        set {
            this.objField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Obj can be one of several classes.

Comment: Something quick to try (if u haven't already) is to use `XmlSerializer` instead of `DataContractSerializer` and see if that fixes your problem. They don't necessarily produce the same output.

Comment: @DeanOC Yes, that solves it! That produced xml pretty much identical to the source file.

Comment: Cool. I'll add it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with using a `DataContractSerializer` is that it is optimized for sending messages between WCF services and won't necessarily produce the same "classic" xml that the `XmlSerializer` does.

In particular, `XmlSerializer` will serialize all public members unless you tell it not to, but for `DataContractSerializer` it won't serialize unless you tell it to. This was done to help make WCF faster; you only get what you ask for.

So, if you're not generating XML for WCF services, I suggest that you use the `XmlSerialiser` instead.